# Can't connect to azure linux VM on port 9200, but ssh works

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

Installed ElasticSearch on a linux VM in Azure, put in on a Vnet with a public IP and a security group with ports 9200 and ssh 22 open.

I can ssh into the VM. On the VM itself, I can reach port 9200.

But on my PC, when I try to hit the {public IP}:9200, I get a 502 bad gateway? Anyone know why?

Comment: mb elasticsearch doesnt listen on *? only listens on 127.0.0.1 or something

Comment: Correct. Needed to change /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml file. See below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, needed to set the following line in the */etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml* file;

BEFORE

```
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
```

AFTER

```
#
network.host: [_local_, _site_]
#
```